# How to create a "Sharepoint Client Application" in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to use the RESTful services provided by Sharepoint 2010 from a .NET C# .asmx service.

At this location: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

Microsoft makes the following claim:

> However, you don't need to manually construct HTTP requests in order
>   to use the SharePoint REST interface. When you use Visual Studio 2010
>   to create a SharePoint client application, Visual Studio will generate
>   a WCF Data Services Framework service proxy when you add a reference
>   to the service. The service proxy provides strongly-typed entity
>   classes and enables you to use LINQ expressions to build queries.
>   Behind the scenes, the service proxy manages the details of building
>   and submitting requests to the service.

However, when I go to create a new project in Visual Studio 2012 I cannot find an option to create a Sharepoint Client application

Am I missing something?

Comment: I dont know if its in 2012: The quote from above says **When you use Visual Studio 2010**

Comment: Maybe this might be of use to you?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539974(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @logix - I thought about that, but why would they remove it for 2012?

Comment: @Orch - that is for a standard console application. I have already been able to implement the same thing in a web applicaiton, however using ClientContext has limited functionality. If I want to access the sharepoint information a client server, I need to use web services.

Comment: What kind of information you cannot get from using the client object model? Or better what are you trying to get? CLient object model performs better than calling web services due to the batch capability

Comment: You cannot get recurring calendar events to expand via ClientContext. However, it turns out you cannot get it from the Rest service either. You must use the Lists.asmx soap service or SPService, which requires that you run the code on a server with sharepoint installed.